# manage.py createsuperuser: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'PathLike'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I'm trying a Django tutorial. For some reason my existing superuser got deleted; creating that went fine, but I can't make another one. This also happens when I try to use pip.

I didn't change anything in the libraries so not sure why this happens now but didn't before. On windows 7 (Python 3.6.3 and Django 1.11). I've seen similar but not the exact same problems for Windows. Still I checked the file and there seems to be a PathLike class.

I've also tried to repair my Python installation but it didn't help. any ideas?

Comment: full stack trace please?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you may have modified the settings.py file. But as MrName mentioned you need to share full stack trace

Comment: I tried to replace with the original. didn't work.

here is what I get after calling and filling in createsuperuser:
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\gzip.py", line 52, in open
    if isinstance(filename, (str, bytes, os.PathLike)):
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'PathLike'

here's after pip install gzip --upgrade:
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\configparser.py", line 691, in read
    if isinstance(filenames, (str, os.PathLike)):
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'PathLike' god bless

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a feature that changed in Python3.6 as you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.PathLike). Make sure that your python version is 3.6 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Python and Django version and that will work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'PathLike'

Installing it into the global site-packages with the below command solved my problem:

```
pip install --user virtualenvwrapper
```